# Share custom story with staged image on Facebook using FB.ui no working

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have the following code that stage the canvas image and then create object to share it using FB.ui. Staging the image and create the object are working without problem but the share dialog not displayed. If I replaced the image parameter in create object with an image url it is working.

is there any wrong in my code:

```
var userAccessToken = $("#user_access_token").val();
var appAccessToken = $("#app_access_token").val();
try {
    blob = dataURItoBlob(dataURL);
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append("access_token", userAccessToken);
fd.append("file", blob);
try {
   var imageURI;
   $.ajax({
        url: "https://graph.facebook.com/me/staging_resources",
        type: "POST",
        data: fd,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("success " + data['uri']);
            imageURI = data['uri'];
        },
        error: function (shr, status, data) {
            console.log("error " + data + " Status " + shr.status);
        },
        complete: function () {
            FB.api(
                'https://graph.facebook.com/app/objects/myappnamespace:myobject',
                'post',
                {
                    access_token : appAccessToken,
                    object:{
                        app_id: myappid,
                        url: "myappurl",
                        title: "Sample Photo",
                        image: {
                            url:imageURI,
                            user_generated:true
                        },
                        description: ""
                    }
                },
                function(response) {
                    var objectId = response['id'];
                    FB.ui({
                        method: 'share_open_graph',
                        action_type: 'myappnamespace:myaction',
                        action_properties: JSON.stringify({
                            myobject:objectId
                        })
                    }, function(response){});
                }
            );
        }
    });
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

finally I found the solution by changing user_generated parameter from true to false

now the code for creating object looks like below:

```
FB.api(
                'https://graph.facebook.com/app/objects/myappnamespace:myobject',
                'post',
                {
                    access_token : appAccessToken,
                    object:{
                        app_id: myappid,
                        url: "myappurl",
                        title: "Sample Photo",
                        image: {
                            url:imageURI,
                            user_generated:false
                        },
                        description: ""
                    }
                }
```